# Create Tabs in TabHost with different content

Tags: android, android-tabhost

In my application I can create Tabs for a TabHost view with this code:

```
TabSpec spec1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("1");
spec1.setContent(R.id.tab1);
spec1.setIndicator("1");   

tabHost.addTab(spec1);
```

My problem now is that I do not know how many tabs I have to create (the number is generated at runtime). For every tab I have to call `setContent` with a layout id but if I use the same layout id for different tabs thees tabs allways have the same content. How can I create so many tabs with different contents as I need?

This is my current code which creats two tabs but with the same layout at all:

```
TabSpec spec1=tabHost.newTabSpec("1");
spec1.setContent(R.id.tab1);
spec1.setIndicator("1");

LinearLayout v = (LinearLayout) tabHost.findViewById(R.id.tab1);
TextView tv = new TextView(getActivity());
tv.setText("Hello World");
v.addView(tv);

tabHost.addTab(spec1);

TabSpec spec2=tabHost.newTabSpec("2");
spec2.setContent(R.id.tab1);
spec2.setIndicator("2");      

tabHost.addTab(spec2);
```

Comment: `but if I use the same layout id for different tabs thees tabs allways have the same content`? That's not true at all, that's an advantage property of tabs, each time you call `addTab()` you're adding different layouts, so what you add to tab "0" is different to what you add to tab "1".

Comment: Hmm... I edit my question. Can you please have a look at the code? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Of course they are the same, because both `spec1` and `spec2` are being assigned `R.id.tab1` as content. If you assigned your `spec2` any different content, the contents would differ.

Comment: Yes but that is my problem. My number of tabs is dynamicly. So for each tab I have to use an other layout id for the `setContent` method. But of course I can't create 20 IDs for the reason that I need 20 tabs. I hope you understand what I mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm attaching you a way of creating tabs dynamically. There's not any difficulty doing them, you just have to be clear what you're doing. I'm adding as much comments as I can:

```
// This function defines the layout itself. In my case, my tab bar is made
// of a customized layout called 'tabs_bg', so I simply inflate my layout.
// You don't need to do this actually if you've enough with the default
// Android's layout. You don't need to call this function explicitely, the 
// function below does that.
private View createTabView(final Context context, final String text) {
  final View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.tabs_bg, null);

  // In my customized layout, I have a TextView and an ImageView, I just set
  // some parameters on them.
  final TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tabsText);
  final ImageView iv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.tabsIcon);

  tv.setText(text);
  iv.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(..., ...));

  return view;
}

// Each time you want to create a new tab, call this method, which
// will call the above one. So if you want to have a TextView as a content,
// you'd call: setupTab(new TextView(this), "My personal tab");
private void setupTab(final TextView view, final String tag) {
  final TabHost th = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

  // The line below will create the tab in the tab bar
  final View tabview = createTabView(th.getContext(), tag);

  // And this code will create the content, take a look at the TabContentFactory part
  final TabSpec setContent = th.newTabSpec(tag).setIndicator(tabview).setContent(new TabContentFactory() {
    public View createTabContent(String tag) {
      // Here tabs_content is created in a similar way than the tab layout itself,
      // with a layout file which is later inflated. All those ID's are from that file.
      final View ll_view = LayoutInflater.from(context.inflate(R.layout.tabs_content, null);
      final TextView view = (TextView) ll_view.findViewById(R.id.tabsContent);

      view.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

      // Anything else you may need... This is the content that should vary
      // on each tab!!!
      view.setText("Hello, this is my tab number: " + th.getChildCount() + 1);

      return ll_view;
    }
  });

  // There you assign your content you just created.
  th.addTab(setContent);
}
```

Comment: Wow really, really great answer. I didn't realize that there is such an interface. Thank you so much for that. That was definitely what I was looking for.